# How to return xml from stored procedure to be parsed in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure that I'm using to generate a list of objects that I'm serializing using XML. The XML object needs to be sent from the database server to the server side where it will be parsed in a controller action. For some reason, an exception is raised at the line where the `SqlCommand` is executed (`using (XmlReader xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())`) and returns the error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

In the stored procedure, I build up the XML objects by creating the root like this:

```
Declare @xmlRoot AS XML
set @xmlRoot = '<SubscriptionsRoot></SubscriptionsRoot>'
```

I then add the sub objects to it like this:

```
set @xmlRoot.modify('insert sql:variable("@XML3")  into (/SubscriptionsRoot)[1]')

set @xmlRoot.modify('insert sql:variable("@XML2")  into (/SubscriptionsRoot)[1]')
```

and finally, to return the xml from the stored procedure, I select it:

```
select @xmlRoot
```

In the controller action, I have:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings....))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "dbname.sp_name";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@newSubscrXml", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newSubscrStr;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@inactiveSubscrStr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = existingSubSecurityIds;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader;    

    using (XmlReader xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
    {
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            var s = xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();
        }
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

What could be causing the issue? Also, how should xml be returned from a stored procedure and parsed in C#?

**EDIT**: The following is the structure of the xml object

```
<SubscriptionsRoot>
  <NotReSubscribed>
    <Subscription>
      <attribute_1>5645</attribute_1>
      <attribute_2>4336565           </attribute_2>
      <attribute_3>gfghgh             </attribute_3>
      <attribute_4>32345        </attribute_4>
      <attribute_5>not Resubscribed</attribute_5>
    </Subscription>
    <Subscription>
      <attribute_1>5435</attribute_1>
      <attribute_2>3446554           </attribute_2>
      <attribute_3>6dgdhgh             </attribute_3>
      <attribute_4>gdh5435354        </attribute_4>

      <attribute_5>not Resubscribed</attribute_5>
    </Subscription>
    <Subscription>
      <attribute_1>23456</attribute_1>
      <attribute_2>h23454           </attribute_2>
      <attribute_3>s345345             </attribute_3>
      <attribute_4>jfgh23454        </attribute_4>
      <attribute_5>not Resubscribed</attribute_5>
    </Subscription>
  </NotReSubscribed>
  <NotNewlySubscribed>
    <Subscription>
      <attribute_3>hjh554</attribute_3>
      <attribute_2>         </attribute_2>
      <attribute_3>sd34534</attribute_3>
      <attribute_4>fsdghfgdhdfgh</attribute_4>
    </Subscription>
    <Subscription>
      <attribute_3>86785</attribute_3>
      <attribute_2>         </attribute_2>
      <attribute_3>a234424</attribute_3>
      <attribute_4>98796896dgf</attribute_4>

    </Subscription>
  </NotNewlySubscribed>
</SubscriptionsRoot>
```

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with your proc logic. Basically you've got some place you're trying (implicitly or explicitly) to cast a varchar value to a bigint. Can you provide the full text of the proc?

Comment: @Xedni Ok, it looks like attribute_1 is actually being derived from a column in the stored procedure that is of type bigint. Does this need to be converted before the xml is creatd?

Comment: I have no idea how you're constructing `attribute_1` because I can't see the code or the variable and how it's being assigned. Simply substituting a variable into a xml.modify clause shouldn't require casting ahead of time though.

Comment: @Xedni I think it would actually just be easier to return a table from the stored procedure instead of an xml object

Comment: Lol yeah, definitely.

Comment: Is inactiveSubscrStr type defined in the stored procedure?  Either the type is defined as BigInt or the driver doesn't have a type so it thinks existingSubSecurityIds looks like a BigInt.  The simple solution is in the stored procedure define inactiveSubscrStr as VarChar.